# Using ImageIO.read to read image through inputstream

Tags: java, image, sockets, io

Im trying to read at the server an image that coming from the client. To show you my problem. i deleted entirely the imageIO.write part from the client. At the server i have a part of code that looks like that:

```
image =ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());
System.out.println("you already read the image");
```

when I run the server i get immediatly a "you already read the image" message. At other read methods like readObject and so on the read method suppose to wait until message arrived from the client. I didnt send nothing from the client, so how it possible that the server recieved immediatly somthing and skipped on? It seems like the server skip ahead on the read method. before i deleted the write method from the client i always got NullPointerException. It seems that the problem is that the server just skip the ImageIO.read.
Am i doing it right?